# Slash between authors in actual cite command not in italics

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

Using jurabib and the package option `authorformat=dynamic` led to the effect, that the slash between two authors was not placed in italics, but upright. The effect can be seen when compiling this MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[authorformat={dynamic}]{jurabib}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{HRG_III_2_Minne_und_Recht,
  author = {Christa Bertelsmeier-Kierst and Albrecht Cordes},
  title = {Minne und Recht},
  booktitle = {Handw\"orterbuch zur Deutschen Rechtsgeschichte},
    pages = {Sp.\,1537\,--\,1541},
  year = {2016},
  editor = {Albrecht Cordes and Hans-Peter Haferkamp and Heiner L\"uck and Dieter Werkm\"uller},
  volume = {III},
  address = {Berlin},
  howcited = {1},
  shorttitle = {Minne und Recht in: HRG~III, 2.\,Auflage},
  volumetitle = {Konfliktbew\"altigung\,--\,Nowgorod}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\textit{Bertelsmeier-Kierst}/\textit{Cordes} $\leftarrow$ Upright

\cite{HRG_III_2_Minne_und_Recht} $\leftarrow$ Cite

\textit{Bertelsmeier-Kierst/Cordes} $\leftarrow$ Italics

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the line `\renewcommand*{\jbbtasep}{/} % bta  = between two authors sep` which basically only redefines what is already defined, the result is changing to:
[image]