# Comma of cite by jurabib not in italics after italic author

Tags: bibtex, jurabib

After I solved a similar problem for jurabib with the slash between authors ([Slash between authors in actual cite command not in italics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451016/slash-between-authors-in-actual-cite-command-not-in-italics)), I am struggling to find the solution for the same problem with the comma after the author set in italics.

You can see in the MWE, that the typesetting obviously changes to `\normalfont` before typesetting the comma, which in my eyes seems incorrect and italics as in the line expected would be preferred.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibformat=tabular,authorformat={dynamic},titleformat=commasep,titleformat=all,commabeforerest,howcited=compare,annote]{jurabib}


\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@InCollection{Althoff_Inszenierte_Freiwilligkeit,
  author     = {Gerd Althoff},
  title      = {Inszenierte Freiwilligkeit. Techniken der Entmachtung im Mittelalter},
  booktitle  = {Herrschaftsverlust und Machtverfall},
    year = {2013},
  address    = {M\"unchen},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Inszenierte}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\cite{Althoff_Inszenierte_Freiwilligkeit} $\leftarrow$ cite

\textit{Althoff}\normalfont, Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ actual

\textit{Althoff,} Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ expected

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\end{document}
```

The corresponding output shows like this:
[image]

Comment: Reads like a comment to causa »Maaßen« in Germany of 2018.

Comment: `\textit{Althoff,}` is going to be *really* hard. I could offer `\textit{Althoff}\textit{,}` but there the italic correction kicks in and leaves a hefty space as well. `{\em Althoff}\textit{,}` looks OK, so it might be an option to try and get rid of the italic correction by using the switch instead of the macro.

Comment: PS: You'll find that `\textit{Althoff},` gives good output, but the kerning there is destroyed by all sorts of operations and thus does not come out as expected in the actual cite macros.

Comment: OK @moewe, I'd accept a non-italic comma, at least the kerning should be fine. I actually think the kerning is the more disturbing fact, but thought solving it by getting the italics right is the better approach. With all the questions regarding jurabib in the last two days I actually think branching jurabib.bst and jurabib.sty for this project would be the simplest approach at all.

Comment: So to formulate your solution, it is actually to redefine `\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfont}{\em}` and `\renewcommand*{\jbactualauthorfont}{\em}`. If somebody comes up with a fix to also have the comma in italics, I'd prefer that, but otherwise this works.

Comment: Did my answer help you or are you unhappy with it?

Comment: The answer came past the time of the last document release. Therefore we went with the ugly quickfix in my own comment. On the weekend I had no time to work on it. Next weekend will be the next sprint, the I can apply the proposed fix, let you know and upvote/accept answer. Sorry for the delay, I didn't meant to be rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. `jurabib` has a modular structure that lets you format many things independently, but that also means that the code is slightly more complex than if you were to typeset these things directly.

In particular the name and the comma are not printed with the same command. So something like `\textit{Althoff,}` is going to be very complicated to achieve. `\textit{Althoff}\textit{,}` on the other hand would be possible but does not give the output you'd like to see due to excessive italic correction. Incidentally `\textit{Althoff},` gets the kerning right (the comma is not in italics, though), but that can not be used here, since the kerning is very fragile and destroyed by all sorts of things (groups, assignments, `\write`s, even a `\relax`).

I could offer a solution that tries to avoid the excessive spacing due to the italic correction in `\textit{Althoff}\textit{,}` by resorting to `\itshape` instead of `\textit`.

```
\newcommand*{\textitnic}[1]{{\itshape #1}}
\textitnic{Althoff}\textitnic{,} Inszenierte
```

The absence of the italic correction is desirable here, but it might lead to tiny problems in other situations, so check your output carefully.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[bibformat=tabular,authorformat={dynamic},titleformat=commasep,titleformat=all,commabeforerest,howcited=compare,annote]{jurabib}


\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@InCollection{Althoff_Inszenierte_Freiwilligkeit,
  author     = {Gerd Althoff},
  title      = {Inszenierte Freiwilligkeit. Techniken der Entmachtung im Mittelalter},
  booktitle  = {Herrschaftsverlust und Machtverfall},
    year = {2013},
  address    = {M\"unchen},
  howcited   = {1},
  shorttitle = {Inszenierte}
}
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand*{\textitnic}[1]{{\itshape #1}}
\renewcommand{\jbhowsepbeforetitle}{\textitnic{,\space}}

\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfont}{\textitnic}%
\renewcommand*{\jbauthorfnfont}{\textitnic}%
\renewcommand*{\jborgauthorfont}{\textitnic}%
\renewcommand*{\jbannotatorfont}{\textitnic}%
\renewcommand*{\jbactualauthorfont}{\textitnic}%


\begin{document}
\textit{Althoff}\textit{,} Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ two textits

\textit{Althoff}, Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ textit and literal comma

\textit{Althoff}\relax, Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ textit and literal comma, kerning inhibited

\textit{Althoff}{,} Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ textit and literal comma, kerning inhibited

{\itshape Althoff}\textit{,} Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ no italic correction, italic comma

\textit{Althoff,} Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ expected

\textitnic{Althoff}\textitnic{,} Inszenierte $\leftarrow$ two textitnics

\cite{Althoff_Inszenierte_Freiwilligkeit} $\leftarrow$ cite

\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

[image: The screenshot shows the output of the *Althoff, Inszenierte* with varying space between the "ff" and the following comma.]